# Google Map KML Layer File Size Limit Issue

Tags: javascript, google-maps, kml

I want to use 84MB KML file to show KML layer on google map but Google map not support more than 10MB KML file.

Google Map Developer Link about Size and complexity restrictions for KML rendering

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer

Please check below code which is I am using to show KML layer in google map. Its working fine with small KML file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>KML Layer</title>
        <style>
            #map {
                height: 80%;
            }
            html, body {
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <a href="#" class="button" data-latLng="cta_red.kml">Red Fibre</a><br>
            <a href="#" class="button" data-latLng="cta_green.kml">Green Fibre</a><br>
            <a href="#" class="button" data-latLng="cta_blue.kml">Blue Fibre</a><br>
        </div><br>
        <div id="map"></div>
        <script async defer
                src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAWsZy8xWxT9yNBvYcO1dpxBzDttr7DqLA&sensor=false">
        </script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                var defaultu = 'cta.kml';
                initMapp(defaultu);
                jQuery(document).on("click", ".button", function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var url = jQuery(this).attr("data-latLng");
                    initMapp(url);
                });

                function initMapp(url) {
                    var myLatLng = {lat: 41.876, lng: -87.624}
                    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                        zoom: 17,
                        center: myLatLng
                    });
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: myLatLng,
                        map: map,
                        title: 'Hello David!'
                    });
                    var kmlurl = url;

                    var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
                        url: kmlurl,
                        map: map
                    });
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please, make yourself as clear as possible when asking questions here. Please, refer: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have updated my question. Hope it will more clear...

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to use a third party KML parser like [geoxml3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) or [geoxml-v3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml-v3/).  Note that due to the size and complexity of the KML file there may be performance issues and it will take a long time to load.

```
var geoXml = null;
var map = null;
var myLatLng = null;

function initialize() {
  myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.422104808,-122.0838851);

  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 18,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.422104808,-122.0838851),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
    myOptions);

  geoXml = new geoXML3.parser({
    map: map,
    singleInfoWindow: true,
  });
  geoXml.parse('cta.xml');
};
```

[live example (with a small KML file)](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_cta_test.html)

Comment: I update my question please let me know how can I use it in my code

Comment: I have tried it but my browser hang when I tried to load 84MB kml file. Please help...

Comment: That is what I mean by "performance issues" (and why Google doesn't let you load big KML files).  There are no size restrictions on geoxml3, it just takes time to transfer the file and memory on the client (your computer/browser) to store it.